# Possible to embed IAM roles or share policies across roles?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I am trying to setup IAM roles for all of my AWS resources. I have a role defined ("default") that I want set on all instances. This role lets it download needed files from a specific S3 bucket as well as get info about instances and volumes.

For some, not all, instances I want to give more abilities such as launch an instance, terminate instance, or get/put access to other S3 buckets.

There are several cases like this. Essentially every role need "default" (see above) role abilities and some instances need various extended abilities.

I can't seem to find any way to share policies across roles or anything similar. Is my only option to create multiple roles and repeat the shared abilities?

Answer (score 1):

Sharing policies across roles is possible indirectly by means of [AWS CloudFormation](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/), which *gives developers and systems administrators an easy way to create and manage a collection of related AWS resources, provisioning and updating them in an orderly and predictable fashion*.

More specifically, the [AWS::IAM::Policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-policy.html) resource *associates an IAM policy with IAM users, roles, or groups*:

```js
{
   "Type": "AWS::IAM::Policy",
   "Properties": {
      "Groups" : [ String, ... ],
      "PolicyDocument" : JSON,
      "PolicyName" : String,
      "Roles" : [ String, ...
      "Users" : [ String, ... ],
   }
}
```

Like this you only need to manage your policies centrally and can update the association with specific IAM entities (users, groups, roles) right there in a source code controlled fashion.

- There's much more to CloudFormation of course, it's a very powerful tool (see [Getting Started with AWS CloudFormation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/GettingStarted.html)).

Comment: It sounds good, but it's pretty vague. Can you give a specific example? How do you reference the policy from a `AWS::IAM::Role`, for example? How do you define the `AWS::IAM::Policy` without indicating a role—or are you implying we should list the roles in the policy? etc.

Comment: Never mind; I provided a [detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76637934) separately.