# AWS Cloudformation define policy once, associate with multiple roles

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

In AWS CloudFront I define two separate roles using [`AWS::IAM::Role`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-role.html). Under `Policies` there is a policy that is common between them. (They both should have identical database access.) Rather than duplicating the policy (which lists a lot of individual actions), I would like to define the policy once and reference that policy definition from each role definition.

I see there is a separate [`AWS::IAM::Policy`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-policy.html) I can maybe use to define the policy, but then how would I reference that within my `AWS:IAM:Role` definition? There's nothing in the [`AWS::IAM::Role Policy`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-iam-policy-1.html) documentation that says I can reference a policy without giving its entire policy document inline.

The `AWS::IAM::Policy` also seems to indicate that a group, role, or user is required. So instead of referencing the policy from the roles, and I expected to define the roles and then separately create a policy that references the existing roles, rather than referencing the common policy from the roles themselves? That seems rather limiting.

I would rather define a policy and then reference it from roles as needed, but is this possible? Or do I have to go all out and create a [`AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-managedpolicy.html) for that?

Comment: An [IAM Role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-role.html) can refer to multiple policy ARNs in `ManagedPolicyArns` and/or include multiple inline policies in `Policies`.

Comment: Add a customer-managed IAM policy (via [AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-managedpolicy.html)) and then refer to it from multiple IAM roles via their ManagedPolicyArns setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This actually has a straightforward answer. Let's say I define a role that allows my ECS service to access my database table for writing. It might look like this:

```yaml
  EcsServiceTaskRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: my-task-role
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: store-in-database
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: 2012-10-17
            Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - dynamodb:PutItem
              Resource:
                - !GetAtt MyDbTble.Arn
```

I also have a lambda that I want to access the database:

```yaml
  LambdaFunctionRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: my-lambda-role
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: store-in-database
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: 2012-10-17
            Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - dynamodb:PutItem
              Resource:
                - !GetAtt MyDbTble.Arn
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - !Sub "arn:${AWS::Partition}:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole"
```

If I don't want to duplicate the policies, there seems to be no way for me to define a policy and reference it *from* the roles. Instead I can remove the policy from the initial role definitions, and define the policy separately, indicating the roles *to which it should be applied*:

```yaml
  EcsServiceTaskRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: my-task-role
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: store-in-database
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: 2012-10-17
            Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - dynamodb:PutItem
              Resource:
                - !GetAtt MyDbTble.Arn

  LambdaFunctionRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: my-lambda-role
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: store-in-database
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: 2012-10-17
            Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - dynamodb:PutItem
              Resource:
                - !GetAtt MyDbTble.Arn
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - !Sub "arn:${AWS::Partition}:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole"

  DatabaseAccessPolicy:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
    Properties:
      PolicyName: store-in-database
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Action:
            - dynamodb:PutItem
          Resource:
            - !GetAtt MyDbTable.Arn
      Roles:
        - !Ref EcsServiceTaskRole
        - !Ref LambdaFunctionRole
```

Interestingly this doesn't seem to create some separate policy entity in the AWS account that I can see (unlike `AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy` undoubtedly would), although it is identified by name. In the IAM console, the policy has been attached to each role separately, as if I would have defined it inline.

CloudFormation has a thousand ways to reference things, and it's inventing new ones all the time. In this case, the approach it takes seems to be a reverse-reference, that is, applying the policy to roles rather than referencing the policy from the roles themselves. Thus using it across CloudFormation stacks might not be as flexible as it otherwise might be. Apparently they want you to use a managed policy for that. But for preventing definition duplication within one CloudFormation template, it seems to work just fine.

Comment: "the policy has been attached to each role separately, as if I would have defined it inline." If you read the documentation you linked in your question https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-policy.html the first sentence says "Adds or updates an inline policy document that is embedded in the specified IAM user, group, or role." So you aren't creating a single shared policy, you are creating duplicate inline policies on multiple roles.

Comment: "So you aren't creating a single shared policy, you are creating duplicate inline policies on multiple roles." Great, that's what I want to do. The point is that I'm not duplicating the policy in my CloudFormation source code. This achieves that. Yes, there is a single sentence in the documentation which, after I've used it seems perfectly clear. But initially reading that terse sentence with no examples left me wanting to confirm my understanding. So I've asked a legitimate question, provided a clear answer, and supplemented the documentation with examples. Why the downvotes?

Comment: That sentence might be terse, but I'm not sure how it could be any clearer. There is a clear distinction between inline policies and managed policies. The documentation clearly says that `AWS::IAM::Policy` creates inline policies. If you have an idea how that could be clearer in the documentation please click the "submit feedback" link on that page.